# Post route error while using async await now i am not able to post a new product

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i was trying to recreate my post route using async await and i messed up dont know how to make it correct again

```
router.post('/', async (req, res, next)=> {
    try{
        const product =  await new Product({
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        name: req.body.name,
        price: req.body.price
        });
        product.save()
        console.log(result);
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    };
    res.status(201).json({
        message: 'Handling POST requests to /products',
        createdProduct: product
    });
});
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: i cannot post my products now earlier i was using promises then i was able to do it properly

Answer (score 0):

Const is scoped to a block, which in this case is inside the try block. The JSON you're returning is outside the try block and therefore, the const product does not exist there, and cannot be used. Put the response inside the try block for it to work.

Comment: ok is it good practise to return json to the front end and showing server errors like that?

Answer (score 0):

1. new Product doesn't return promise.
2. Product will not accessed out of scope to send response

```js
router.post('/', async(req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const product = new Product({
      _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
      name: req.body.name,
      price: req.body.price
    });
    const result = await product.save()
    console.log(result);

    res.status(201).json({
      message: 'Handling POST requests to /products',
      createdProduct: product
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)

    res.status(201).json({
      error: err.message
    });
  };

});
```

Comment: i dont understand how to replace promises with async await.

Comment: ok let me explain something.

// init function with async keyword and return result using return.
async function b(){
return  'i am aysnc'
}

Comment: then when to write await?